# Weird if Statement Behaviour

Tags: c++, if-statement, int, cin

When the following code comes to the cin statement: If I input -1, it still runs my invalidSelectorError() found in the last else if section... even though that section is supposed to be passed if mainMenuSelector is equal to -1.

Why??

(By the way, after invalidSelectorError() runs, the while loop encasing everything works and the programs terminates as expected.)

```
int mainMenuSelector;

while(mainMenuSelector != -1){
    cout << "--- MAIN MENU -----------------" << endl;
    cout << "[1] Create New Contact" << endl;
    cout << "[2] View Existing Contacts" << endl;
    cout << "[3] View or Edit Data Fields" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Or just press ENTER to quit." << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Selection: ";

    mainMenuSelector = -1;
    cin >> mainMenuSelector;
    cin.ignore();

    if(mainMenuSelector == 1){
        contactCreator();
    }else if(mainMenuSelector == 2){
        contactViewer();
    }else if(mainMenuSelector == 3){
        dataFieldViewer();
    }else if(mainMenuSelector != 1 ||
             mainMenuSelector != 2 ||
             mainMenuSelector != 3 ||
             mainMenuSelector != -1
             ){
        invalidSelectorError();
    }
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if(mainMenuSelector != 1 &&
         mainMenuSelector != 2 &&
         mainMenuSelector != 3 &&
         mainMenuSelector != -1
         ){
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in this part:

`else if(mainMenuSelector != 1 ||
         mainMenuSelector != 2 ||
         mainMenuSelector != 3 ||
         mainMenuSelector != -1
         ){
invalidSelectorError();`

You are using ||. So as long as one of those four statements separated by the ||'s is true (and that will always be the case, for obvious reasons), then your code will enter the block of code after the 'if'